# MFMailComposeViewController - edit body but not recipients and subject

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a `MFMailComposeViewController` wherein I want to edit the mail body, but I want the mail recipients to be fixed which will be already there when mail opens.

I tried setting `setEditing` as **NO**. But I don't get what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple reference document on [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) states that

> **Important** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In
>   addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not
>   allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may
>   still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes
>   are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before
>   presenting the interface.